# resize array while keeping mask

Tags: arrays, algorithm, resize

I'm trying to figure out how to effectively resize an 1-d array while keeping the mask it represents. Using this array i do draw simple sprites while one value in the array represents a specific color.

Anyway my goal is as follows, having the following "small" array with values:

```
0, 1, 2, 3,
0, 1, 2, 2,
0, 1, 1, 1,
0, 0, 1, 1,
0, 0, 0, 0
```

This obviously is going to be a sprite of size 4x5.

Now i want to resize it keeping the values so getting the same sprite/shape but in higher resolution.

Now by saying "scale-by-2" i would get a 8x10 sized sprite, the 1-d array then should look as follows:

```
0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3,
0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3,
0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2,
0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2,
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

My idea is to group the numbers row by row, take the scale factor (2) and add as many of the digits (from one group) as we have to scale (2) in one row. Then duplicate each row by the scale factor as well. But still i am not sure if this covers all cases.

Any other (more effective) way to handle this?

Comment: Do you know dimensions of the array? If not, then answer is ambiguous. If yes, then your problem is not different from handling 2d-array directly.

Comment: this is a 1-d array as i wrote above. what do you mean by not different than 2-d? 1-d means i have only one loop to work through. the first array above is 1-d interpreted in a 4x5 manner, so first 4 int values represent first row of the pixel sprite.